# I want the demand to be increased byt one only when battery energy reaches a certain value

Tags: netlogo, turtle-graphics

```
globals [ demand1 stimer energy_c_evehicle1 energy_b_evehicle1 scaling_factor]
breed[endusers1 enduser1]
to setup
  clear-all
  reset-timer
  reset-ticks
  set stimer 0
  world_scaling
  create-clusters
create-enddistributor
  dec_timer
   set energy_b_evehicle1 5 * 1.56

to create-clusters
   ask patches with [pxcor <= -70 and  pycor <= 30 and pycor > 20]   [set pcolor green]
  ask patches with [pxcor = -70 and pycor = 25] [set plabel "cluster 1"]
end

to  create-enddistributor
  ask patches with [pxcor = -69 and pycor = 25] [set pcolor brown]
end

to world_scaling
  set scaling_factor (world-width / (world_scale * 1000)) ;; patches per meter
end



to create_endusers1
  create-endusers1 numcluster1
  [
    move-to one-of patches with [ pcolor = green ]
    set color white
    set shape "triangle"
    set size 2
    ]
end
to call_dist1
  foreach sort endusers1 [ ?1 ->
    ask ?1
    [

     set demand1 demand1 + 1

    ]
  ]
end

to calculate_endusers1

    every 1 [ ask endusers1[ set energy_c_evehicle1  avgspeed_evehicle * 0.147]];  each evehicle consumes
    every 1 [ set energy_b_evehicle1  energy_b_evehicle1 - energy_c_evehicle1]; energy left in battery
                                                                  ; each battery= 1.56kWh, 5 such battery needed
end
to demand_battery
 ask endusers1
  [if energy_b_evehicle1 < 1.56 [call_dist1]]
end
to dec_timer
  every 1
  [
   set stimer stimer + 1
  ]
end

to-report timer-expired?
   report ( stimer >= 24 )

end


to go

  calculate_endusers1
 demand_battery
  dec_timer

  tick

if  timer-expired? [ stop]
end
```

**In my simulation, I am building a solar plant,I want the demand to increase by one for each enduser1 if energy _b _evehicle1 < 1.56. But here the demand is increasing by 1, every tick after the energy_b_evehicle1 is below 1.56. I do not want the demand to keep increasing every 1 tick, I want it to increase the demand only one time after the energy reached a certain value. How can I relate the number of ticks to real time in my simulation? Please help me with this.**

Comment: In reading your code, I'm a bit confused.  Is each endusers1 supposed to have have their own battery(ies)?   They don't in our code, but your comments suggest that they should.

Comment: Yes each endusers1 will be supplied with a battery to consume.

Comment: Which, then, of your  variables refer to an individual battery?  I'm assuming `energy_c_evehicle1`  and `energy_b_evehicle1`.  Any others?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to have to make some assumptions here about the structure of your model. First, it seems that `energy_c_evehicle1`, `energy_b_evehicle1` and `demand1` are variables that refer to each `endusers1`'s battery. Therefore, they should be defined as `endusers1-own` variables rather than as globals. (As globals, each `enduser1` is working on the same battery.)

```
endusers1-own [
  energy_c_evehicle1
  energy_b_evehicle1
  demand1
]
```

The initialization of `energy_b_evehicle1` would then move from `setup` to `create_endusers1`.

```
to create_endusers1
  create-endusers1 numcluster1 [
    move-to one-of patches with [ pcolor = green ]
    set color white
    set shape "triangle"
    set size 2
    set energy_b_evehicle1 5 * 1.56
  ]
end
```

Now each enduser1 will be working with her own battery and demand. You might make those changes and see how that affects the behavior of your model.

One other observation: In `demand_battery` you ask every enduser1 to `call_dist1`.  But in `call_dist1` you ask every enduser1 to increment her demand.  Thus every enduser1 is asking every enduser1 to increment her demand, so every enduser1's demand will be incremented numcluster1 times.  I doubt that is what you want.  Should `demand_battery` simply be

```
to demand_battery
  ask endusers1
  [if energy_b_evehicle1 < 1.56 [set demand1 demand1 + 1]]
end
```

Each enduser1 would then check only her own battery and increment her own demand if the condition is met.